# Making a game like Mastermind in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game like Mastermind in Python but by using numbers [1-9] instead of colours. The game needs to be a little complex however and that is where I am struggling. I want to be able to randomly generate a password of 5 digits between [0-9] and make the user have 10 tries to get it right. If they guess a number correctly, I want to tell them where it is in their list and ask them to keep going as well. So far, I have this:

```
import random

random_password = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range (5)]

for counter in range (10):
    guess = input ("Crack the Mastermind code   ")
    if guess != random_password :
        print ("Guess again  ")
#Here I am trying to make it find out if it has a didgit correct, tell them where
#and ask the them to keep guessing. once count runs out, I want it to say they lost
    elif guess 
    else print ("Sorry, you lose :(  ")
if guess == random_password :
    print ("Congrats, you win!  ")
```

Any help is appreciated overflow bros, I am lost. I know that I need it to access items from a list. Would using a function like append work?

EDIT: This is my new code. Sorta works however my output is now showing it is wrong even when I guess the number correctly. It wants me to input with '' and , to separate the list but I shouldn't have to have the user do that to make the game function.

```
import random

random_password = [str (random.randint(0,9)) for i in range (5)]

for counter in range (10):
    guess = input(str ("Crack the Mastermind code   ") )
    if guess != random_password :
        print ("Guess again  ")
#Here I am tryin to make it find out if it has a didgit correct, tell them where
#and ask the them to keep guessing. once count runs out, I want it to say they lost
    for i in random_password:  
        if(i in guess):
            print (i)
        if guess == random_password :
            print ("Congrats, you win!  ")
else :
    print ("Sorry, you lose :(  the correct answer was.... ")
    print (random_password)
```

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces and describe in words the steps needed to solve the problem. For example, "to make it find out if it has a didgit correct" requires getting the digits from the number. Figure out how to do so. This is an ideal candidate for a function `def get_digits(n)` that returns a list of digits.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it quickly is to create a small function that will check if any of your string answer (from input) match with any characters of the password list

Also I change the order of your condition statement to make it more clear and efficient.

Finally I change your random_password from LIST to STRING because then you will be able to do guess == random_password properly.

Hope it helps!

PS:

IF you use Python2.X you should change input to raw_input (to get    string value) else if you use Python3.X just keep it this way

```
import random

def any_digits(guess,password):
    for character in guess:
        if character in password:
            return True
    return False

random_password = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in [random.randint(0,9) for i in range (5)]])

print(random_password) 
print(type(random_password))

for counter in range (10):
    guess = input ("Crack the Mastermind code   ")
    if guess == random_password :
        print ("Congrats you win!  ")
    elif any_digits(guess, random_password):
        print ("Some numbers are correct!  ")
    else:
        print ("Guess again  ")

print("No more chances, you lose...") 
print("The code was ", random_password)
```